# How to pass parameter by Swagger into req.body in Express/Node?

Tags: swagger

```
 "/auth/sign-in": {
      "post": {
        "summary": "Sign-in on the site.",
        "description": "You can sign in on the site by using login and password.",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "email",
            "description": "You should pass here email",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "password",
            "description": "You should pass here password",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Here you will get token",
            "example": {
              "token": "token"
            }
    },
```

Above you can see my swagger.json route ( as an example of my code ) . I need to find out how to send value in req.body( by using swagger ) . I see that we can pass parameter in `path`(directrly in link , also we can pass it in `cookie` ,also in `header`, and in `query`)

```
         {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "email",
            "description": "You should pass here email",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
```

I need to help with creating this object for getting parameter email in next way ( `req.body.email` ). How can I make it?

Answer (score 2):

elyas-bhy have helped me so  much . I will give you more info about this answer .

```
  "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "description": "You should pass here email",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "email": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "password": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
```

it will be looks like this one :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySqsk.png)

Hope someone else it will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @swagger
 *    produces:
 *      - "application/xml"
 *      - "application/json"
 *    parameters:
 *      - name: level_id
 *        in: path
 *        required: true
 *      - name: body
 *        description: Please enter an email here
 *        in: body
 *        required: true
 *        schema:
 *          $ref: '#/definitions/levels'
 *    responses:
 *      201:
 *        description: updated
 *      404:
 *        description: Not found
 *      500:
 *        description: Internal Server error
 */
```

Comment: You want to use "\`\`\`" around your code for the formatting to be a lot better. Also, please explain what is it you're posting, more precisely

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenAPI 2.0:

```
{
  "in": "body",
  "name": "body",
  "description": "Resource payload",
  "required": true,
  "schema": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "email": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "required": ["email"]
  }
}
```

Source: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-request-body/

Comment: Thanks ) You 've helped me ) I can't give you +1 m because I don't have permission for this ,but I hope someone who can make it will give you it )

Comment: You can do it yourself, there is a delay of 15 minutes after having posted a question before you can accept an answer, You can try again now.

Comment: my reputation less then 15 ( that is the reason why I can't)

Comment: You might not be able to upvote the answer, but you can at least accept this answer in order to mark the question as resolved :) That should also increase your reputation if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
"/your-path": {
    post: {
        summary: 'Example POST request',
        description: 'Test post',
        "consumes": [ "application/json" ],
        produces: ["application/json"],
        requestBody: {
            content: {
                "application/json": {
                    schema: {
                        "properties": {
                            "user": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "pass": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        responses: {
            '200': { "description": "OK" },
            '401': { "description": "Unauthorized" },
            '402': { "description": "Bad Request" },
            '500': { "description": "Internal Server Error" }
        }
    }
}
```